# How to force TimeSpan to be depended with enabled/disabled button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan

I have a TimeSpan textbox, my objectif is to disable the button Save when the form of TIMESPAN is wrong (exp 90:00:00)..

I try a code, it is correct for just once time..if I set 20:10:00 ..The Save button is enabled (correct).
After that however the TIMESPAN is wrong 55:00:00, the button is enabled ( and the saving in database is 00:00:00)

The XAML :

```
 <TextBox Name="txtTime"  Margin="10,10,10,10" >
                <TextBox.Text >
                    <Binding Path="Time" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" Mode="TwoWay" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:DateTimeValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

The ViewModel :

```
public bool  VarTIME ;



  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Time is required")]
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set
        {
            time = value;
            intervalString = Time.ToString();
            TimeSpan reded;
            bool success = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(intervalString, "hh\\:mm\\:ss",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out reded);

            if (success)
            {
                VarTIME = true;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }


    public SheduleTrainViewModel()
    {
        VarTIME = false;
        addTrain = new RelayCommand<string>(AddTrainFunction, canAddTrain);

        private bool canAddTrain(string obj)
         {     return VarTIME;     

         }
    }
```

The VelidationResult class:

```
 public class DateTimeValidationRule: ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string time;
        Regex regex;
        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        else
            time = value.ToString();

        regex = new Regex(@"^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?$");
        if (regex.IsMatch(time.ToString()))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "The time must match this format hh:mm:ss / hh:mm");
    }
}
```

How I can fix it to be work always correct?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a `TimeSpan` property to anything else than a valid `TimeSpan` value so doing the validation in the setter of the source property is meaningless.

`value` is *always* a valid TimeSpan.

You should perform the validation in the `ValidationRule`:

```
public class DateTimeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        TimeSpan reded;
        if(!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value.ToString(), "hh\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out reded))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid time!");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

It this validation fails, the `TextBox` will get a red border (using the default Validation.ErrorTemplate) that indicates that the value cannot be converted to a `TimeSpan` and the property won't be set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I modified my post to dispaly the ValidationResult, how I  can add your suggession in my class ?
thanks,

Comment: I just moved the validation logic from the view model to the ValidationRule. Of course you can use any validation logic you want. The point is that there is no reason to validate the TimeSpan in the setter of the source property in the view model, because if you get there, you always have a valid TimeSpan.